# JPA and second level cache. The cache does not turn on

Tags: java

I use TomEE, JPA with Hibernate.
I save my simple entity Student in the DB using persist, after I check my Entity in the cache 2 level, and get false. Why? How can i turn on cache?

my entity Student

```java
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment",strategy = "increment")
    int id;

    private String userrname;

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Student.FIND_ALL";

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Student(String userrname) {
        this.userrname = userrname;
    }

    public Student() {
    }

    public String getUserrname() {
        return userrname;
    }

    public void setUserrname(String userrname) {
        this.userrname = userrname;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myPerName777" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>ee.Student</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.shared-cache-mode" value="All" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jpa1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and main Main class

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory myFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPerName777");
        EntityManager entityManager = myFactory.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        Cache cache = myFactory.getCache();

        transaction.begin();
        Student jonny = new Student("Jonny");
        entityManager.persist(jonny);

        entityManager.persist(new Student("max"));
        entityManager.persist(new Student("max"));
        entityManager.persist(new Student("max"));

        entityManager.persist(new Student("mike"));
        entityManager.persist(new Student("mike"));
        transaction.commit();                                      //All entities saved in DB. Its'ok

        System.out.println(cache.contains(Student.class, 1));       //return False, WHY?

        entityManager.close();
        myFactory.close();
    }
}
```

All entities saved in DB, but when I want to get status in cache, I get false. Why?

Comment: Try defining the cache strategy for the entiti:

@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

Comment: Beppe C, thank you! 
I used this anotation over my Entity, and import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;   but word "used" in anotation is red, and i have error: java: incompatible types: javax.persistence.Cache cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation 
Maybe other seting i need enter?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the Hibernate example (the one I am more familiar with), you need to look at the corresponding JPA, maybe here https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Cacheable

Comment: Beppe C, thank's, i will read it )